# Automatically enter the names of people on a list into a website's search engine and store returned info

Tags: web-scraping

I am a novice programmer (I only have been using Java and Matlab for a year) and need to take a list of 100 people at my school and find their emails so that I can send these people an email about tryout info for my Frisbee club.

I can manually enter each name into my school's people search website and it will return their email. Is there anyway to write a script to do this automatically?

The source code of the search page says its of the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But first, what language are you using?

Comment: One way: use a bash script that calls wget.

Comment: Hey, I'd like to use Java ideally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use irobot free software to do this. It is very good at such kind of job.

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn how to use curl or wget
2. [usually don't get this step for free] wrap curl or wget in a script or code of your choice language
3. Play frisbee!

Comment: yeah...i think i need to go back to school for another year before I can mess around with this stuff hahah